# Node JS and npm installtion for SPFX sharepoint webpart

Tags: node.js, npm, sharepoint, npm-install, spfx

I am trying to install node js and npm for Sharepoint SPFX Web part.( Node Version: v14.4.0, Npm Version: 6.14.5).
When I try "gulp trust-dev-cert" getting below errors:

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:39:5
    at req_ (\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (D:\VM_NodeJS\GetSharePointListItems_001\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

Bellow error when i run : gulp serve command

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:39:5
    at req_ (\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

--

Please help to me install the right version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPFX only support Node.js 10.x.
[image]

You could get this information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment